# Symfony3 locale after login ( redirect to default locale)

Tags: php, symfony, locale, translate

I have problem in Symfony project with Symfony version 3.1.10.
I got this project to finish translating and this is my first meeting with Symfony.

What is problem here: 
I have two language DE and EN, default language is DE.
When someone go to login page or home page( where also is login form) and switch to EN and enter to login, its change locale to /de/ default language, after login.
I spent few days on this bug and really I need help. I tried everything, but there is still no progress.

I followed Symfony documentation, how to configure translation, how to use Sticky user session and I created everything same, but bug is there agin.
I will show my code below:

**config.yml**

```
imports:
    - { resource: parameters.yml }
    - { resource: security.yml }
    - { resource: services.yml }

parameters:
    locale: de
framework:
    #esi:             ~
    translator:      { fallbacks: ["%locale%"] }
    default_locale:  "%locale%"
```

**app/config/routing.yml**

```
fos_user:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/all.xml"

app:
    resource: "@AppBundle/Controller/"
    type:     annotation

proreg:
    path:     /{_locale}/product/registration
    defaults:  { _controller: ProductRegistration\Controller\ProductRegistrationController::productRegistrationAction }
prolist:
    path:     /{_locale}/profile/products
    defaults:  { _controller: ProductRegistration\Controller\ProductRegistrationController::listAction }
prodel:
    path:     /{_locale}/profile/products/delete/{id}
    defaults:  { _controller: ProductRegistration\Controller\ProductRegistrationController::deleteAction }
proadd:
    path:     /{_locale}/product/register
    defaults:  { _controller: ProductRegistration\Controller\ProductRegistrationController::createAction }
```

**app/config/security.yml**

```
security:
    providers:
        fos_userbundle:
            id: fos_user.user_provider.username_email

    firewalls:
        # disables authentication for assets and the profiler, adapt it according to your needs
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false

        main:
            pattern: ^/
            form_login:
                provider: fos_userbundle
                login_path:   fos_user_security_login
                # csrf_token_generator: security.csrf.token_manager # Use form.csrf_provider instead for Symfony <2.4
                always_use_default_target_path: false
            logout:       true
            anonymous:    true
            # http_basic: ~
            # http://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#a-configuring-how-your-users-will-authenticate

            # form_login: ~
            # http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/form_login_setup.html

    encoders:
        FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface: bcrypt

    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
        ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: ROLE_ADMIN

    access_control:
        - { path: ^/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/register, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/resetting, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/admin/, role: ROLE_ADMIN }
        - { path: ^/sso/login_check, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/sso/settoken, role: ROLE_ADMIN }
        - { path: ^/profile/products, role: ROLE_ADMIN }
        - { path: ^/product/registration, role: ROLE_ADMIN }
```

**app/Resources/FOSUserBundle/all.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>

<routes xmlns="http://symfony.com/schema/routing"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://symfony.com/schema/routing http://symfony.com/schema/routing/routing-1.0.xsd">

    <import
        resource="@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/security.xml"/>
    <import
        resource="@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/profile.xml"
        prefix="/{_locale}/profile" />
    <import
        resource="@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/registration.xml"
        prefix="/{_locale}/register" />
    <import
        resource="@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/resetting.xml"
        prefix="/{_locale}/resetting" />
    <import
        resource="@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/change_password.xml"
        prefix="/{_locale}/profile" />
</routes>
```

**app/Resources/FOSUserBundle/security.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>

<routes xmlns="http://symfony.com/schema/routing"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://symfony.com/schema/routing http://symfony.com/schema/routing/routing-1.0.xsd">

    <route id="fos_user_security_login" path="/{_locale}/login" methods="GET POST">
        <default key="_controller">FOSUserBundle:Security:login</default>
    </route>

    <route id="fos_user_security_check" path="/login_check" methods="POST">
        <default key="_controller">AppBundle:Security:check</default>
    </route>

    <route id="fos_user_security_logout" path="/logout" methods="GET POST">
        <default key="_controller">FOSUserBundle:Security:logout</default>
    </route>

</routes>
```

**src/AppBundle/Controller/DefaultController.php**

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Controller;

use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Security;
use Symfony\Bundle\SecurityBundle\SecurityBundle;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;

class DefaultController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("/{_locale}", name="homepage", defaults={"_locale": "de"})
     */
    public function indexAction(Request $request)
    {
        // replace this example code with whatever you need
        return $this->render('default/index.html.twig', [
            'base_dir' => realpath($this->getParameter('kernel.root_dir').'/..').DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR,
        ]);
    }
```

**src/AppBundle/Controller/SecurityController.php**

```
<?php

/* 
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

// src/UserBundle/Controller/SecurityController.php
namespace AppBundle\Controller;

use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use FOS\UserBundle\Controller\SecurityController as BaseController;

class SecurityController extends BaseController
{
    public function loginAction(Request $request)
    {
        $response = parent::loginAction(request);

        // ... do custom stuff

      $errors->messageData = "Test";
      $errors->messageKey = "test";

        $error = $error ? $error : $errors;
        return $this->renderLogin(array(
            'last_username' => $lastUsername,
            'error' => $error,
            //'csrf_token' => $csrfToken,
            'origin' => $request->get("origin")));
    }
    public function checkAction()
    {
        $response = parent::checkAction();
        die  ("<pre>" .print_r($response). "</pre>");
    }
}
```

**src/AppBundle/Event/LocaleListener.php**

```
// src/AppBundle/LocaleListener.php
namespace AppBundle\Event;

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\GetResponseEvent;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\KernelEvents;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;

class LocaleListener implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
    private $defaultLocale;

    public function __construct($defaultLocale = 'de')
    {
        $this->defaultLocale = $defaultLocale;
    }

    public function onKernelRequest(GetResponseEvent $event)
    {
       $request = $event->getRequest();
       if (!$request->hasPreviousSession()) {
           return;
        }
        //print_r($request->get('_locale'));
        // try to see if the locale has been set as a _locale routing parameter
        if ($locale = $request->attributes->get('_locale')) {
            $request->getSession()->set('_locale', $locale);
        } else {
            // if no explicit locale has been set on this request, use one from the session
            $request->setLocale($request->getSession()->get('_locale', $this->defaultLocale));
        }
    }

    public static function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return array(
            // must be registered after the default Locale listener
            KernelEvents::REQUEST => array(array('onKernelRequest', 15)),
        );
    }
}
```

**login form**

```
<form action="{{ path("fos_user_security_check") }}" method="post" id="login-form" class="col-xs-12">
<div class="content">
   <h2>{{ 'index.login.regcust'|trans }}</h2>
   <p>{{ 'index.login.haveaccount'|trans }}</p>
   <ul class="form-list">
      <li class="form_element">
         <label for="email" class="required">{{ 'index.login.email'|trans }}<em>*</em></label>
         <div class="input-box"> 
            <input type="hidden" name="origin" value="{{ origin }}" />
            <input type="hidden" name="_target_path" value="{{ path("setSSOToken") }}" />
            <input type="email" name="_username" value="" id="username" class="input-text required-entry validate-email" title="{{ 'index.login.email'|trans }}">
         </div>
      </li>
      <li class="form_element">
         <label for="pass" class="required">{{ 'index.login.password'|trans }}<em>*</em></label>
         <div class="input-box input-box-password">
            <input type="password" name="_password" class="input-text required-entry" id="password" title="{{ 'index.login.password'|trans }}">
            <!--a href="" class="f-left forgot-password">{{ 'index.login.forgot'|trans }}</a-->
         </div>
      </li>
   </ul>
   <p class="required required_hint">
      <em>*</em> {{ 'index.login.required'|trans }}
   </p>
</div>
<div class="buttons-set">
   <div class="button_wrapper">
      <button type="submit" class="button" title="Anmelden" name="send" id="send2"><span><span>{{ 'index.login.submit'|trans }}</span></span></button>
   </div>
</div>
</form>
```

If someone can help me how to fix this problem, i will be very grateful.
Thanks

Comment: is that happening only after the login?

Comment: Yes, only after login or logout

Comment: it should be the default setting, but can you add `session_fixation_strategy: migrate` under `security:` in `app/config/security.yml`?

Comment: also, can you show the html form on the `/{_locale}/login` page?

Comment: I added session_fixation_strategy:  migrate under security, but still same problem. Also I have updated code in question, check login form. Thank you

Comment: If you use `always_use_default_target_path: true`, do you still have that problem?

Comment: Then it redirects to a homepage but with default language DE.Still same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I am sure this is related to your config. Let's try one more time programmatically:

1) In src/AppBundle/Event/LocaleListener.php change

```
namespace AppBundle\Event;
```

to

```
namespace AppBundle\EventListener;
```

and make sure it is registered according to https://symfony.com/doc/3.1/session/locale_sticky_session.html:

```
services:
app.locale_listener:
    class: AppBundle\EventListener\LocaleListener
    arguments: ['%kernel.default_locale%']
    tags:
        - { name: kernel.event_subscriber }
```

2) Remove

```
/{_locale}
```

from app/Resources/FOSUserBundle/security.xml and append

```
prefix="/{_locale}"
```

to

```
<import
    resource="@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/security.xml"
```

in app/Resources/FOSUserBundle/all.xml. This is mostly just to keep the config in one place.

3) Make sure you have

```
firewalls:
    main:
        form_login:
            login_path: fos_user_security_login
            check_path: fos_user_security_check
            default_target_path: <your_desired_route>
        logout:
            path: fos_user_security_logout
```

in app/config/security.yml with the locale.

4) In app/config/security.yml you should define the correct paths for access_control:

```
access_control:
    - { path: ^/(en|de)/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/(en|de)/register, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/(en|de)/resetting, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/(en|de)/admin/, role: ROLE_ADMIN }
    - { path: ^/(en|de)/sso/login_check, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/(en|de)/sso/settoken, role: ROLE_ADMIN }
    - { path: ^/(en|de)/profile/products, role: ROLE_ADMIN }
    - { path: ^/(en|de)/product/registration, role: ROLE_ADMIN }
```

including the locales. Otherwise those paths won't be protected by the firewall. Also you should make sure register, resetting and any other routes correspond to the ones in FOSUserBundle.

**Edit**

It looks like this was related to another controller which altered the FOSUserBundle behavior.